# Can EOA accounts interact with ERC-4337 paymasters?

Tags: gas, wallets, eoa, erc-4337

My question is rather simple.
**Can an EOA account pay some coins using ERC-4337 paymasters without having to pay gas fee itself**?
Is there any way, having access to an **EOA** private keys, to withdraw funds from the account without having to pay the gas fee? I thought ERC-4337 allows me to do so. Have I been mistaken?